# Excel Special Paste Link to expanding data

Tags: excel, paste

For example, I have two worksheets in my workbook.  One workbook is for data only, it has 10 columns but the number of rows can increase or decrease.

I'm able to use the paste link special function on worksheet two, to link to the current data but is there a way that I can automatically update the link so that if I add additional rows on the Data worksheet that those will also appear on the other spreadsheet?

I'm hoping I'm clear on this.

Thank you for your help.
Jim

Comment: Is there a reason you want links to the data instead of say turning the data into an Excel Table and referencing it with formulas? Perhaps you could outline further what it is you are trying to do with these linked cells.

Comment: @jeffreyweir I'm not sure how to do this, basically, I have data in one worksheet that will grow by rows.  I want to refer to that data in other worksheet and ensure that any new data added will appear on the other worksheet.

Comment: Hi Jim. Is there any particular reason why you need to make an exact copy of the data in the same workbook? Normally you only want one copy of your raw data. If you want a subset of that data to show in another sheet, the best way to achieve this is by using something called a Pivot Table. If you can explain more about what it is you are wanting to do with the raw data then we're better placed to give you an optimal solution that you might not be aware of. :-)

Comment: @jeffreyweir There will be a number for worksheets with additional columns so for explain the raw data might have columns A to E but we would have additional columns per row from column F - K.  So on the "custom" worksheet, I would like to A to E (all rows) and Column F - K.  Plus the "cusom" worksheet will have certain formatting.    I'm thinking also it will be easier for me to update the worksheet with the raw data via C# and not go near the customised worksheets.  I'm pulling the raw data from a sharepoint application.  The architect isn't my design, just trying to figure out a simple solu

Comment: Will the additional columns be for data input, or will they display the results of formulas? (Or perhaps both)

Comment: @jeffreyweir It will be a bit of both.

Comment: Ok. You really need to use VBA for this. Are you comfortable with implementing a VBA solution should I find the time to code it up?

Comment: @jeffreyweir, apologies I thought I had replied.  I came to the same conclusion but instead I used C#, ADO and interop.  I found the ADO had a limitation of 255 characters for updates,so I switched part of the code to interop.

Answer (score 0):

As @jeffreyweir stated, you do need to use code for this.  In this case, I used ODE in C# .net after searching stackoverflow for examples.
Jim